# PostgreSQL complex update operation on column

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpql

I'm trying to update every row which has place_id (fk) but db says the result of select is has more then one row. Of course it does has more then one row, because I'm trying to update column, not only one record.

```
update Event set placeListingName = 
    (select substr(coalesce(epc.shortTitle, epc.title),1,100) 
    from Event e join e.place p join p.publicContent epc 
    where e.place is not null) 
where place is not null
```

the expression in brackets (select ... where e.place is not null) works well and returns a list of Strings

Comment: Have you heard of the `on` clause?

Comment: Is this JPQL? (because it looks like)

Comment: I think a simple `Event = e` in the inner `WHERE` clause could be enough. I'm not sure though that `UPDATE` supports sub-queries in every JPA implementations. (Hibernate will probably work)

Comment: I don't get what you mean :/. The problem is the result of select is a column of Strings and not a physical column in any table

Comment: The reason you are getting an error is not because you are trying to update more than one row. You are getting the error because your subquery should only return one row but it's returning multiple. A subquery in the SET clause must only return one row.

Comment: @kret you will always get multiple results in the sub-query, unless you give a condition to the sub-query's `WHERE` clause, which can match a single row in the sub-query to a single row in the target table. `WHERE Event = e` should do that (if you have a primary key in the `Event` entity).

Comment: That sounds extremally logically. I will check it tomorrow, but thank you very much. Oh wait. Probably publicContent table doesn't have fk to Event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone interested:

```
update Event e set e.placeListingName = 
    (select substr(coalesce(epc.shortTitle, epc.title),1,100) 
    from Event ev join ev.place p join p.publicContent epc 
    where ev.id = e.id) 
where e.place is not null
```